# Как подключиться к MySQL БД на хостинге?

Tags: c#, mysql, unity3d

Доброго дня! Недавно начал изучать программирование. Начал с Unity3d использую C#. Пишу приложение для своей пекарни. Изучил по совету Форумчан MySql создал БД, купил домен и хостинг. Через CPanel в phpMyAdmin добавил свою БД, начал писать скрипт для получения данных из БД и застрял, мучаюсь 3 день, потому решился спросить здесь.

```
public class Menu : MonoBehaviour {

private string connectionString;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    connectionString = "Data Source=localhost:3306;database=dexigesc_idamdi;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx";
    GetScore();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}
private void GetScore ()
{
    using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        dbConnection.Open();

        using (IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
        {

            string sqlQuery = "Select * from menu";
            dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
            using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Debug.Log(reader.GetString(1));

                }
                dbConnection.Close();
                reader.Close();
            } 
        }
    }

}
}
```

Выдает ошибку

> EntryPointNotFoundException: sqlite3_key
>   Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3.SetPassword (System.Byte[] passwordBytes)
>   Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open () Menu.GetScore () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/Menu.cs:33) Menu.Start () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/Menu.cs:21)

Если удалить User Id и Password из connectionstring ошибка следующая SqliteException: SQLite error no such table: menu

Я намеренно менял имя сервера и БД выдает такую же ошибку. Из чего я сделал вывод что проблема в подключении. Что я делаю не так. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: вы говорите про MySQL, а в коде указано  SqliteConnection. SQLite - это другая СУБД, не MySQL

Comment: пример кода брал с инструкции на сайте. Подскажите тогда как получить данные с моей бд, или ссылку на пример или хоть что нибудь. Спасибо!

Comment: прочитайте пожалуйста вот это [ask]

Comment: Вам нужно использовать MySql поставщик данных. Для этого нужно скачать и подключить соответствующую библиотеку, либо воспользоваться NuGet'ом. И затем `SqliteConnection` заменить на `MySqlConnection`